# Как определить объединена ли ячейка с другой?

Tags: vba, excel

Скажите, пожалуйста, как, используя `cells`, определить объединена ли ячейка с другой.
По сути мне нужно выгрузить в форму (в ComboBox) названия рядов, но эти названия относятся сразу к нескольким рядам (т.е. ячейки объединены по вертикали).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем понятна задача.
Проверить, объединена ли ячейка с другой (другими):

```
If Worksheets("Лист1").Cells(1, 3).MergeCells Then MsgBox "Таки да!"
```

При объединении значение ячеек, кроме левой верхней, теряются. В таком случае для создания списка для ComboBox не обязательно проверять, объединены ли ячейки, достаточно проверить ячейки на наличие данных. Код, создающий список элемента формы:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim n
'        создать выпадающий список
    With Worksheets("Лист1")
        Set Rng = .Range("C1:H4") ' присвоить переменной диапазон "шапки" таблицы
    End With

    ' цикл по ячейкам
    For Each n In Rng.Value
        If n <> "" Then ' если в ячейке есть данные
            Me.ComboBox1.AddItem n ' добавить строку в список
        End If
    Next n
End Sub
```

P.S. В расчетных таблицах старайтесь по возможности не объединять ячейки, могут быть проблемы с вычислениями.